# Conditional clauses, use of 'if, then, else' in major non-English languages?

Tags: linguistic-typology, list-of-languages, logic, clauses, conditionals

Are there major languages in the world that construct conditional clauses differently than English? That is, the translation of "if" and associated words would not be direct due to different structuring of conditional speech. In German, for instance, "if" is translated directly to "wenn" and conditional clauses are constructed similarly to English. Are there any languages that differ significantly from this "linguistic model" of logic?

I'm trying to understand whether there is some relativity in how logical, conditional thoughts are expressed in different languages and cultures.

Comment: IF is one of the Natural Semantic Metalanguage's semantic primes, so it at least exists in every language.

Comment: @curiousdannii: In German, the word for "if" can be dropped sometimes, as in *Wäre jetzt gerade schönes Wetter, dann würde ich draußen sein* "If the whether were nice right now, I'd sit outside".

Comment: Unfortunately, this nice question is not covered by [WALS](http://wals.info)

Comment: English makes a distinction based on whether there is - or the speaker acknowledges - a possibility that a future condition will not be fulfilled. Hence *if you get the job, we'll celebrate* contrasts with *when...*. English speakers might be slow to accept that the version with *when* is conditional at all. Not all languages make such a distinction. An old Thai schoolbook has a mother saying to her daughter *if you're as old as your brother, you'll go to school too*. Sometimes an *if* in the original language will not be directly translated, but will become *when* in English.

Comment: if/then/else are frequently talked together, but I'm not sure if there's anything common among them, linguistically speaking. It feels like they just happen to be used together a lot, like none/my/business or happy/new/year.

Comment: @jk-ReinstateMonica Mandarin has at least three different words meaning ‘if’ (要是 _yàoshi_ and 如果 _rúguǒ_ which head the conditional like _if_, and 的话 _de huà_ which comes at the end of it; frequently used together, 要是/如果……的话), but all of them can also be omitted with the conditional quality being only inferrable from context, and often ambiguously so: （要是/如果）你给我买票（的话）（那）我（就）跟你去 _yàoshi/ruguǒ nǐ gěi wǒ mǎi piào (de huà), (nà) wǒ (jiù) gēn nǐ qù_ ‘if you buy me a ticket, I’ll go with you’. Note that you can leave out the markers in English too: “You buy me ticket, I’ll come with you”.

Comment: @jk-ReinstateMonica English also allows "Were it sunny, we'd sit outside".

Comment: @curiousdannii Thank you, that answers the question.

Comment: @curiousdannii It's often asserted  but there's no evidence to back it up. Lot's of languages don't need any word comparable to *if* to make a conditional. There's no evidence in English either that *if* itself has any kind of conditional meaning. That's just often blindly assumed.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Are you referring to "if" being optional in some languages or are there languages without the word? NSM theory as indicated by curiousdannii proposes "if" as one of universal primitives. On the other hand, your point about "if" in English having no "kind of conditional meaning" is a good one and the reason I asked the question. (To me, "if" appears to be a prompt, a command to a supposition. But I digress...)

Comment: Even where it means *supposing that...*, it still relates to a condition. I think the point was that if you can drop *if* and still have a conditional meaning, it's plausible that the conditional meaning was not in the *if* in the first place.

Comment: @Theod'Or, rchivers I believe there are languages where there is no marking at all on the conditional antecedent/protasis, and only on the consequent/ apodosis. (Not in my post because I couldn't remember any examples). But even in English, in addition to your point, there's additional evidence that *if* has no meaning. For, example "If you should see Bob, ask him to phone me" means exactly the same as "Should you see Bob, ask him to phone me". They've got exactly the same lexical items apart from the second's got no *if*! (A point from my PhD thesis). So as rchivers says ...

Comment: @rchivers But does it relate to a condition? e.g. *If you're hungry, there's some biscuits on the sideboard*. And even such conditionals as seem to suggest a condition don't actually seem to have any condition there on close inspection e.g. *Bob plays tennis if it's sunny* (Bob may play tennis every day regardless of the weather). And then there's examples such as *If you offered me a million pounds, I still would not betray my friend Bob*, where the offer is not a condition for the loyalty.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Well, I think so. The point of *if you’re hungry* is to explain why I’m telling you *there's some biscuits...*, by pointing to a condition which may be satisfied at some point and would make this relevant information. In context, I suspect the same would be true for *Bob plays tennis*, eg A *it was sunny that day – Bob would have been down at the beach* B *no, Bob plays tennis...*. B is denying that *sunny weather* conditions *Bob does not play...*. Equally, *if you offered...* is denying that some small inducement would be a sufficient condition for me to betray B.

Comment: These are just thoughts off the top of my head and if you’ve done a PhD in the area then you will obviously have considered the whole subject in a lot more depth. The point I was really reaching for was that cross-linguistic differences in the scope of conditional structures are probably at least as interesting as differences in the structures themselves. The Q did seem to me to assume that a conditional is whatever German treats as a conditional, though I’m having second thoughts about that in the light of the OP’s last comment.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I’m fairly sure there are also languages where neither protasis nor apodosis is marked. I have a vague recollection of hearing this described about some Austronesian language at some point, though I don’t remember which one it may have been. Also, how are you defining _condition_ here? If you’re talking about a narrow, mathematical sense, I’ve never heard of any structure in any natural language that has the ability mark that. Lojban probably can, but that’s not natural.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes, I believe there are languages like that. However, although they'd be translated as conditionals, whether they in fact are 'conditionals proper' is up for debate, as they do not seem to have a conditional adjunct plus main clause structure. The exact nature of linguistic condition is hotly debated. Re 'mathematical' condition (aka material implication), all languages have the ability to express this, because every material implication can be expressed using a disjunction, in other words using the word *or*.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet So *Not P or Q* is logically equivalent to *If P, Q*, if we understand the latter to be a material implication. In other words *If Bob's here, he's in the attic* is equivalent to *Bob's not here or he's in the attic* if one believes that *if*-conditionals are essentially material implications!!!

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Yes, but in all languages that I’m familiar with, such disjunctions also have other functions that don’t map to conditional statements, in the same way that _if_ also relates to both conditional and non-conditional statements. I’m not familiar with any languages that can unambiguously mark true conditionals – all the ways that I know of to mark conditionals can also be used to mark similar but non-conditional statements.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Are you saying that such "disjunctions" have functions that don't map to logical disjunctions?

Answer (score 4):

In many languages, for example Bengali, the word comparable to *if* is optional and frequently absent, whereas the word marking the apodosis (usually with a similar function to *then*) is mandatory, exactly the opposite way round to English.

Of course, it's dubious whether *then* has an inherent connection with conditionals in English.

Answer (score 2):

As for the order of things:

`"In conditional statements, the conditional clause precedes the conclusion as the normal order in all languages. (...) (Greenberg 1963: 84, #14)`
(https://typo.uni-konstanz.de/raraneu/universals-archive/501/)

As for the question if there are words for "if", "then" and "else" in all languages: No idea, maybe someone else can answer. My guess would be, no. See also jk's comment that in German, the conjunctive makes the word "if" redundant. In English, you could also say: "Had they told me this, ..." instead of "If they had told me this, then ...". You can surely leave away "then" in these two languages, and replace "else" with "or". I think that we are entering pragmatics territory here, meaning it's not only logic and compositional semantics, but also their actual (conventionalized) interpretation.

*Greenberg, Joseph H. (1963).
Some universals of grammar, with particular reference to the order of meaningful elements. In Greenberg (ed.) 1963, 73-113. Greenberg, Joseph H. (1964 [1965, 1978e]). Some generalizations concerning initial and final consonant sequences (Russian) Voprosy jazykoznanija 1964-4, 41-65. Translated in Linguistics 18: 5-34. Also published in Greenberg (ed.) 1978, Volume 2, 243-279.*

Comment: What is Greenberg’s argumentation for protasis > apodosis being “the normal order”? Why is “If you buy me a ticket, I’ll come with you” any more ‘normal’ or ‘basic’ than “I’ll come with you if you buy me a ticket”?